# Can't connect to aws mysql rds from mysql workbench for some region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created aws mysql rds for different region with `public` access configuration from my free tier account.

Following were the regions:

- N. virginia
- Singapore
- Mumbai

For the above regions, I can connect only to `N. virginia` region rds from my local mysql workbench. But for other two regions, I am not being able connect to the workbench.

Is there any limitation for other regions?

Comment: Did you check the security config of the instances you are accessing? maybe you're missing your IP in the whitelist of the regions that dont let you connect

Comment: @victorperezpiqueras do we really need the IP white listing as I created the database with public access configuration? 
Also for N. virginia region, it is working but for the other two region it is not working with same db configuration.